# Referencing two models at the same time

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have a booking table which points to bookings on either room_bookings or restaurant_bookings table a room or restaurant table the migration are

Booking:

```
Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->morphs('booking');
        $table->morphs('business');
        $table->boolean('status');
}
```

room_bookings:

```
Schema::create('room_bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('from');
            $table->string('to');
}
```

restaurant_bookings:

```
Schema::create('restaurant_bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('table_no');
}
```

Restaurant:

```
Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('name');
}
```

Room:

```
Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id'); 
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('number_of_rooms');
}
```

In previous projects I used to define single relationship to the model. I want to save the booking id ,class and room/restaurants id and class and class name on the table.

Before I defined realtionship on single class as

```
    $boking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
     //Defined relationsip on the model as booking()
    $room->booking()->create($data)
```

The Models are as follows

Business.php

```
class Booking extends Model
{

    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

on Room.php and Restaurant.php

```
public function booking()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Booking::class, 'booking');
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Booking::class, 'business');
    }
```

Comment: Relationships are defined in the Models. Do you have any and how do they look like?

Comment: Apologies, I see you mentioned Models already. But I don't fully understand your problem. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @matthiku please see the updated question for the realtionshi[

Comment: I want to add two relationship in a single model so that i can connect them.
Eg. When room booking is made the booking_type field has to store the RoomBooking and business_type has to store Room